# Replace new line in string

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, securitycenter

I have a Logic App that is being triggered when there is a Security Alert in Security Center.

I have a step where I map a subset of the inputs into a JSON document and use that to create a file.

I need the JSON document that I'm creating to all be in one line, so I need to make sure I replace any control line feeds in the inputs.

Example input:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "RemediationSteps": "[\r\n  \"1. Enforce the use of strong passwords\",\r\n  \"2. Add the source IP to NSG block list for 24 hours\",\r\n  \"3. Create an allow list for RDP access in NSG\"\r\n]"
    }
}
```

My mapping (in the Designer):

```
replace(triggerBody()?['RemediationSteps'], '\r\n', ' ')
```

However, I'm still getting new lines in my JSON document.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your replace function. Have you checked the raw output of the action that is doing the replace? Can you still see the '\r\n' substrings there?

Comment: Is triggerBody() returning actual JSON?  Some Triggers emit base64 content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. You have to literally use an "enter". This is what it looks like:

```
json(concat('{"items":',string(split(outputs('GetAttachmentContent'),'')),'}'))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Fellipe, you can format your code by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button at the top of the editor. You can edit your answer with the button at the bottom.

Answer (score 9):

When edited in design view, logic apps adds a backslash to the original backslash to cancel it out. If you go to Code view you can remove it manually.

From:

```
"value": "@{replace(items('...')['...'],'\\\r\\\n',' ')}"
```

To:

```
"value": "@{replace(items('...')['...'],'\r\n',' ')}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Had same issue, and this was the only solution I could find that worked for me.
Just go to code view and fix it there, so simple...

Answer (score 3):

The above solutions didn't work for me in a Microsoft Flow as the web editor adds extra backslashes. There is no code editor option. What worked was to uri encode the string and then to do a replace:

```
decodeUriComponent(replace(uriComponent(body('bodyitem')?['bodykey']),'%0A','%3Cbr%3E'))

'%0A' is the '\n' uriencoded and '%3Cbr%3E' is '<br>' uriencoded.
```

First encode, do the replace then decode. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Literally putting a new line in the expression worked for me:

```
replace(triggerBody()?['Body'], '
', '<br/>')
```