# LogicApp Split and Replace having problems with \n

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have been trying to split a string into an array of each line `\n`
As this doesn't work I tried `replacing replace(outputs('Compose_6'),'\r\n','@')` with a view to then splitting on  `@`.

I have searched the internet and tried various things but nothing seems to work.

Can someone explain how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us your input data? Please add it as the json that goes into your action where you’re trying to split.

Answer (score 1):

Using **split(variables('string var'),'\n')** expression, you can split string into array. By default logic app will add an extra black slash to original back slash. So suggesting you to change expression in code view as mentioned above.

- I have created logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- In first initialize variable action, taken a string variable with text as shown below

```
Hello
Test split functionality
Using logic apps
```

[image]

- Next initialize variable action, using a array variable and assigning value using expression as split(variables('string var'),'\n'). Make sure you dont have double back slash added in code view. Only one back slash should be there when you see it in code view.
  [image]
  Code view:
  [image]
- The output of logic app can be shown below,
- [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679595/replace-new-line-in-string) thread.